# merging and reading multiple sheets in an excle file

Tags: r, excel

I am facing problem, while trying to merge files. I have and excel file containing 27 sheets, total records 1.8M. In the first sheet the header exists, the other sheets do not have an header. Each file has four columns.
Fist column is for time, etc.

I am trying to read and merge the file but it is not working.

I am using two methods:

**Method 1**

```
excel_sheets(filepath) -> Tabnames

list_all <- lapply(Tabnames, function(x) read_excel(path=filepath,sheet=x, col_names=F ))
DF <- rbind.fill(list_all)
```

In this method the file column merges but the time format changes.

The actual time format was  `7:37:19 PM` after above code the time format changes like this  `0.423726851855462`.

**Method 2**

```
loaded <- map(Tabnames, function(x) read_excel(path=filepath, sheet =x,col_types = "text")) %>%
  `names<-`(Tabnames) %>%   
  bind_rows(.id = "Tabnames")

str(loaded)
```

In this approach the number of variables increased from 4 to 71 as well as the header generated any random number.

Comment: some one please help ..i am stuck

Comment: dear dkv10, there is a total of 1.8M records.. but excel only have 1048576 rows/sheet.  Can we split the task to two, then re-combine both using csv ?